# what's the more elegant way to use an id already set? jQuery("#"+ t)?

Tags: jquery

i'm kinda of a newbie in javascript, even though i built so far lots of working website and apps..

btu i feel naive the way i used to pass the variable id to jquery..
for instance i used to do like this epsecialy when i have to work with some old code
..
let's assume that i have all my website already coded with 'a' tags like this

```
<a id='myId' onclick='doSome(this.id)' > link </a>
```

and then in JS

```
function doSome(id){

//old code removed and replaced by jquery
    jQuery("#"+ id).show();

}
```

and the function in that way works flawless...

so, again, assuming that i cannot change anything else than the code inside the function what's the best way to use the variable id?
because as far as i know if I had used just

```
jQuery(id).show();
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#"+ id).show();
```

it wouldn't have worked...right?

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is to never use string concatenation in a query, there are usually cleaner ways to do something.

Comment: The whole question's moot, since you can't click on an invisible tag, and if the tag is visible `.show()` will do nothing ;)

Comment: @Abe Miessler: if this website was smart enough to remind you , even by email, that you have to "accept" an answer maybe i woudl do it...this website lacks of any good UI for some random user like me..and also why shoudl i have to pick one if none of them are good enough as answers??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing `this.id`, pass `this`

Then you can call the function like:

```
$(id).show();
```

Comment: This is a better solution - instead of performing another lookup for the element, you're passing it and wrapping jQuery around it.

Comment: +1 - If it must be inline this is the way, though I'd rename the variable ;)

Comment: This is nice, but I just realized that this would mean you **can** change the code on the HTML page, and if you can do that, then you should remove all inline JS anyway....

Comment: this is interesting, but as said I'm talking about (rare) cases where I can NOT choose what to pass because the previous code is already written..

Comment: @frankB:  In that case, I would reassign id as soon as I got into the function `id = '#' + id;`  Then you could use JQuery like I posted as many times as you needed throughout.

Answer (score 6):

> jQuery(id).show();

indeed doesn't work, because the argument to the `jQuery`/`$` function is a selector, not an ID.

`'#'+id` works as a selector, but only as long as the characters in the `id` are valid for use in a selector and don't need escaping.

In HTML4/XHTML1, only the alphanumerics plus `.:-_` are valid in IDs, so you only have to worry about `.` and `:`. If you did `'#'+id` where `id` was `a.b` you'd actually be selecting an element with ID `a` and class `b`. In HTML5 many more characters are valid in IDs, so crudely appending the id to `#` is even less reliable.

Using the plain old DOM instead of a selector is less jQuery-ish, but it's safer and (trivially) faster:

```
$(document.getElementById(id))
```

In any case, relying on an `id` to select an element when you already have access to that element is silly: `document.getElementById(this.id)` is obviously going to be the same as `this`.

If you can change the markup at all, you would be better off just passing `this` to the function, then you could lose the selector/getElementById, and if you don't need it for anything else you could lose the `id` attribute too. Even better, avoid inline event handler attributes completely and assign the event handler from script, eg using jQuery `$('#myId').click(function() { ... });`; inside the function, `this` will be the element in question.

Though I don't quite understand what the code is supposed to do... `show()`ing the `myId` onclick of `myId` seems a bit redundant as it'd have to be shown already in order for you to have clicked on it.

Answer (score 1):

bobince already covered how to use `$(document.getElementById(id))` if you cannot change the code.

I just wanted to add the use of `arguments` and some examples that are better than inline JS:

---

I would simply **pass the clicked element** instead of passing the ID and then finding the element again.

It's a good practice to separate markup from functionality. This helps with maintainability and accessibility.

So I would write your HTML like this:

```
<a id='myId'> link </a>
```

To attach a click handler to a particular anchor, I would use the ID to target it, making use of **[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**. Here's what `doSome()` and the handler would look like:

```
function doSome() {

      // Make use of the automatically created
      //   arguments array. This can make things
      //   very flexible.
    arguments[0].hide();

      // You can't click on invisible elements, so 
      //   maybe you meant hide() and not show()?
}

  // When the document is ready....
$(function() {
    $("#myId").click(function(event) {

          // call doSome with the element
        doSome($(this));

          // prevent the page changing
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r9YUN/)**

---

If you want to target all tags instead of just one:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {

      // call doSome with the element
    doSome( $(this) );

      // prevent the page changing
    event.prevendDefault()
});
```

And here is why using **[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)** can be so useful. With it, it's easy to hide all elements passed to doSome:

```
function doSome() {
    $.each(arguments, function() {
        this.hide();
    });    
}
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BdRrS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it requires the `#` as its a css selector. You can't tidy that up any more apart from using the `$` instead of `jQuery` (assuming you have no conflicting scripts already using the `$`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
jQuery("myId").show();
```

Will lookup for **tags** that have this name, not id.

See syntax:

```
jQuery("myTag");
jQuery("#myId");
jQuery(".myClass");
```

See [jQuery selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).